# Lost data at CP -r <from source> <To destination> How to do Recovery

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, data-recovery, data-loss

I took a backup into external hard disk and moved all of them to my new Ubuntu machine location /tmp which is near around 100 GB. And I moved via command prompt

cp -r /tmp /home

The folder into my /home folder. But my /home location had low space. But source folder size is 7.7 GB and designation /home is 4 GB. I forget to notice that at the time of coping. When i start coping I got some low space message and the action stopped.

After error message I couldn't see my source files. Please forgive me if make any mistakes in this posting.

Comment: cp -r shouldn't remove the original files...

Comment: Hi Matt,

cp -r didn't deleted my files. But when i did cp -r , there is some space related error thrown in console and coping process stopped.This is what happened and i looked my source file location, those files were deleted.

Comment: By the way, you should probably have posted this on superuser.stackexchange.com.  It will get more responses as this isn't a question about programming.